# TreeView in iOS application

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, treeview

I'll develop a iOS application for ipad.

I need to represent data in a tree, with (+) for expand element and (-) for shrinking of subelements, and in front of each node there is a button, how can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: what is your current search results for this? if you tell us, this would be easier to answer your question on what have you tried and what have to try.

Comment: something like this? http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/uiexpandabletableview

Comment: no, The tree that I need is similar to CPropTree library in C++

Comment: you can see this link http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/proptree/proptree3.gif, but instead of the color palette, I need to have a button

Comment: I found this example in google code but missing button in front of node, http://code.google.com/p/treeview-4iphone/

Comment: Well, you can add a button to the contentView of the cell. When the user taps it you can animate it to point down, and when tapped again animate it to point to the right. Given that you can get a whole class minus this one small thing, I'd think you'd be pretty happy right now.

Answer (score 1):

The Apple [sample project](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html) might inspire you a little. Actually all you need to do is to change the data model and the cell/header views appearance (and you might want to remove `UITapGestureRecognizer` from the header views using only the button).