# Tree view using UITableview

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have to display the following hierarchial data in UITable View plz give some suggestion
     data will be from plist and will be in following form :

---

```
item 0:
            NODEID:0
            PARENTID:0
            LEVEL:0
            CHLID NODES: (NSARRAY)
                 item 0:
                        NODEID:0
                        PARENTID:0
                        LEVEL:0
                        CHLID NODES: (NSARRAY)
            up to n level

    item 1:
            NODEID:0
            PARENTID:0
            LEVEL:0
            CHLID NODES: (NSARRAY)
```

First of all i am using section header for top level nodes and at runtime I want it to expand when user will click on button.So how to insert row to n number of section and update the datasource as well.

Comment: I haven't had a need of a Tree View - but maybe this QA will suggust some solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194932/treeview-in-ios-application

Comment: Found out this link http://dotnet.kapenilattex.com/?p=566 through googling. Just hav a look. May b useful..

Comment: Thanks HRM it helped me a little ..still some more help needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find out the child nodes on the fly.

```
NSPredicate*thePredicate=
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.mNodeID == %@",aNodeID];
    NSArray*theChildNodes=[NSArray arrayWithArray:[mNodes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:thePredicate]];
```

Filter the nodes using its nodeID to get child nodes once user will click to expand the row.

[image]